# How to rename site collection?

Tags: powershell, site-collection

I want to change the title of a site collection. If I do this in the site settings and get the title via powershell it still shows the old name? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the powershell for it

```
#Get the Web
$Web= Get-SPWeb "http://your-sharepoint-site.com"

#Set the Title & Description
$Web.Title = "Marketing Portal"

#Update the changes
$web.Update()
```

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/02/change-title-description-and-icon-with-powershell.html

Check this video as well.
http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/tutorials/customization/change-site-title/#

Comment: I found out that if I just change the capitalization of a word in the title (via gui or ps) the output of ps still is the old one. I have to rename it to something else and then to the correct title.

Answer (score 2):

After setting the title of a site collection (title of the root web site in the site collection) in the site settings, you should get a new reference to the site, and then query the `Title` property:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://YourSharePointSite
$site.RootWeb.Title
```

Simply using a `$site` reference you got before renaming the site will return the original title:

```
$site.RootWeb.Title
```

If the change has an effect should you see on the web UI.

Furthermore, if the culture of your SharePoint site does not match to the culture of your Windows (for example, a German site on an English Windows), and you would like to read / set your site title from `PowerShell`, you might have issues because of the [Multiple Language User Interface (MUI)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-multiple-languages-available-for-your-sites-user-interface-085242f5-95cb-4b32-9fe6-1ecaa6fe81b3). See [this post](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/getting-and-setting-language-dependent-field-titles-using-powershell/) about how to use the right culture from `PowerShell`.